# Is the Ice Bear scooter 600cc engine made by Honda?

Tags: honda, scooter

I'm looking at several silver wing bikes. Ones is a 2007 and $ 3995 from a dealer but I have to get it shipped to me. There are other scooters I'm looking at also. One is named Ice Bear and is a little more. The 150cc has a Honda engine. There is also an Ice Bear that is 600cc. Does this have a Honda engine as well?

Comment: Do you have a link you can share?  I can't find with the google.

Comment: The largest engined bike Ice Bear appear to do is a 300cc